# groupBy with multiple test functions

Tags: list, haskell

Is there a better and more concise way to write the following code in Haskell? I've tried using `if..else` but that is getting less readable than the following. I want to avoid traversing the `xs` list (which is huge!) 8 times to just separate the elements into 8 groups. `groupBy` from `Data.List` takes only one test condition function: `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]`.

```
x1 = filter (check condition1) xs
x2 = filter (check condition2) xs
x3 = filter (check condition3) xs
x4 = filter (check condition4) xs
x5 = filter (check condition5) xs
x6 = filter (check condition6) xs
x7 = filter (check condition7) xs
x8 = filter (check condition8) xs
results = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only traverses the list once:

```
import Data.Functor
import Control.Monad

filterN :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterN ps =
    map catMaybes . transpose .
    map (\x -> map (\p -> x <$ guard (p x)) ps)
```

For each element of the list, the `map` produces a list of `Maybe`s, each `Maybe` corresponding to one of the predicates; it is `Nothing` if the element does not satisfy the predicate, or `Just x` if it does satisfy the predicate. Then, the `transpose` shuffles all these lists so that the list is organised by predicate, rather than by element, and the `map catMaybes` discards the entries for elements that did not satisfy a predicate.

Some explanation: `x <$ m` is `fmap (const x) m`, and for `Maybe`, `guard b` is `if b then Just () else Nothing`, so `x <$ guard b` is `if b then Just x else Nothing`.

The `map` could also be written as `map (\x -> [x <$ guard (p x) | p <- ps])`.

Comment: Very elegant, though I think Landei's answer is more efficient.

Comment: I'm not so sure. For a start, Landei's reverses the entire list before doing anything.

Comment: After some discussion elsewhere, I came up with a nicer implementation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The new answer is really nice!

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on one traversing the list only once, you can write

```
filterMulti :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterMulti fs xs = go (reverse xs) (repeat []) where
  go [] acc = acc 
  go (y:ys) acc = go ys $ zipWith (\f a -> if f y then y:a else a) fs acc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
map (\ cond -> filter (check cond) xs) [condition1, condition2, ..., condition8]
```

Comment: This is traversing the list again for each condition.

Comment: But is multiple traversals with simple functions slower than one traversal with a complicated function?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `groupWith` from [GHC.Exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Exts.html#v%3agroupWith).

If you write the `a -> b` function to assign every element in `xs` its 'class', I belive `groupWith` would split `xs` just the way you want it to, traversing the list just once.

Answer (score 1):

`groupBy` doesn't really do what you're wanting; even if it did accept multiple predicate functions, it doesn't do any filtering on the list. It just groups together contiguous runs of list elements that satisfy some condition. Even if your filter conditions, when combined, cover all of the elements in the supplied list, this is still a different operation. For instance, `groupBy` won't modify the order of the list elements, nor will it have the possibility of including a given element more than once in the result, while your operation can do both of those things.

This function will do what you're looking for:

```
import Control.Applicative

filterMulti :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterMulti ps as = filter <$> ps <*> pure as
```

As an example:

```
> filterMulti [(<2), (>=5)] [2, 5, 1, -2, 5, 1, 7, 3, -20, 76, 8]
[[1, -2, 1, -20], [5, 5, 7, 76, 8]]
```

Comment: this looks like an elegant solution but could you confirm this is not causing the list to be traversed each time for each condition.

Comment: It does traverse the list each time, but so does the example you gave in the question. You can't filter the same list multiple times without traversing it multiple times.

Comment: I took it from the "separate the elements into 8 groups" that we don't need to filter the list, just split it into separate groups without omitting any elements...

Comment: @nietaki If that's the case, then my mistake. I was merely trying to emulate the behavior of the original example in a more concise manner. The example he gave is equivalent to what I wrote, just longer and more tedious to type. :)

Comment: @vis If your condition functions overlap and you're only traversing the list once, how should it behave if a given list element satisfies more than one of the conditions?

Comment: In my original code, an item may meet more than 1 condition. In that case, it is added to more than 1 group (sublist).

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to nietaki's answer (this should be a comment but it's too long, so if his answer is correct, accept his!), the function `a -> b` could be written as a series of nested `if ... then .. else`, but that is not very idiomatic Haskell and not very extensible. This might be slightly better:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)
import GHC.Exts (groupWith)

f xs = groupWith test xs
   where test x = elemIndex . map ($ x) $ [condition1, ..., condition8]
```

It categorises each element by the first `condition_` it satisfies (and puts those that don't satisfy any into their own category).

(The documentation for `elemIndex` is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aelemIndex).)

Answer (score 1):

The first function will return a list of "uppdated" lists and the second function will go through the whole list and for each value uppdate the list

```
myfilter :: a -> [a -> Bool] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
myfilter _ []   []   = []
myfilter x f:fs l:ls | f x       = (x:l): Myfilter x fs ls
                     | otherwise = l:Myfilter x fs ls


filterall :: [a] -> [a -> Bool] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterall []   _  l    = l
filterall x:xs fl l:ls = filterall xs fl (myfilter x fl l)
```

This should be called with `filterall xs [condition1,condition2...] [[],[]...]`

Comment: Don't forget that a name of function in Haskell cannot start with a capital letter.